# Using SwiftHTTP library for HTTP GET request

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, get

Need assistance with the following

I am using SwiftHTTP library and is trying to get the download link using savefrom.net

For example, by simply accessing http://sfrom.net/https://youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns, the website would redirect us to the download link

However, the output from the response doesn't contain the download links but just a long list of the javascript functions.

## Here is my code

```
 var targetURL = "http://sfrom.net/https://youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns"
 var request = HTTPTask()
     request.requestSerializer = HTTPRequestSerializer()
     request.requestSerializer.headers["Referer"] = "http://en.savefrom.net"

     request.GET(targetURL, parameters: nil, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
     if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("response: \(str!)") //prints the HTML of the page
         }
     },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in

    })
```

Instead of using GET, i tried on the post request this time simulating clicking on the download button for  - http://en.savefrom.net

```
var postParameters = ["sf_url":"https://youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns",
        "new":"1"]

    var postURL = "http://en.savefrom.net/savefrom.php"
    var request = HTTPTask()

    request.POST(postURL, parameters: postParameters, success: {(response: HTTPResponse) in
        if let data = response.responseObject as? NSData {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("response: \(str!)") //prints the HTML of the page
        }
        },failure: {(error: NSError, response: HTTPResponse?) in

    })
```

The post_output again return a long list of javascript function

Comment: No bug here, the content you get *is* the page content. The "redirect" is a content refresh made with JS inside the page, it is not a true HTTP redirect.

Comment: Yes but I am not getting the desired page output. If you try to access the link directly using your web browser, it will direct you to the page with the download link. But not when I tried to do it using the API method, something is missing which I can't figure it out.

Comment: I know. I tried in a browser. And watched the JavaScript in the console. Hence my comment.